# Avoid duplicate elements in the result

Tags: java

I am parsing through the HTML page using jsoup and extracting the links and text corresponding to those links.

I am storing link as value and text as a key in Map. By default Map should not allow me to enter the duplicate elements but here
I am getting duplicate elements in the result.

Can anyone help me with the solution? Here is my code.

```
public class ParseHtmlStrInHashMap {
public static String linkText;
public static String linkHref;
public static int i = 1;

public static Map<Set<String>, Set<String>> pageURLsAndText(Set<String> linkText, Set<String> linkHref) {

  Map<Set<String>, Set<String>> map = new HashMap<Set<String>, Set<String>>();
  map.put(linkText, linkHref);
  return map;

  /*for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
      System.out.println("Key = "+entry.getKey()+", value = "+entry.getValue());
  }*/
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

  //ParseHtmlStrInHashMap phtml = new ParseHtmlStrInHashMap();

  Document doc = null;
  try {
    doc = Jsoup.connect("URL").get();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

  Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
  for (Element link : links) {
    linkHref = link.attr("abs:href");
    linkText = link.text();

    if(linkText.isEmpty()) {
      /*linkText = "Amazon"+i;
      i++;*/

      if(linkHref.contains("=")) {
        String arr[] = linkHref.split("=");
        int j = arr.length-1;
        linkText = arr[j];
      }
      else {
        String arr[] = linkHref.split("/");
        int j = arr.length-1;
        linkText = arr[j];
      }

    }

    Set<String> setHref = new HashSet<String>();
    Set<String> setText = new HashSet<String>();
    setHref.add(linkHref);
    //setText.add(linkText);

    if(setText.contains(linkText)) {
      linkText = linkText.concat(String.valueOf(i));
      i++;
      setText.add(linkText);
    }
    else {
      setText.add(linkText);
    }
    //System.out.println("Text = "+linkText+", URL = "+linkHref);
    Map<Set<String>, Set<String>> map = pageURLsAndText(setText, setHref);

   for(Map.Entry<Set<String>, Set<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
     System.out.println("Key = "+entry.getKey()+", value = "+entry.getValue());
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to [reduce the sample code and to show the input and expected output](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score -1):

It appears you are trying to store Strings are key-value pair in your HashMap.  Yet, your HashMap isn't set to store Strings.

Modify the HashMap from

```
Map<Set<String>, Set<String>> map = new HashMap<Set<String>, Set<String>>();
```

to

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

That will fix your problem

Comment: Hi Kabir, Thank you for your response.i tried the way u told me but even this giving me duplicate keys.. just try with amazon as the url..